# Error invoking runJavaCode: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method runJavaCode on channel com.javacode1/myChannel)

Tags: java, android, flutter, connection, cross-platform

[This error is occured!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr9Ai.png)

## platform_cahnel.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PlatformChannel {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      MethodChannel('com.javacode1/myChannel');

  Future<void> runJavaCode() async {
    try {
      print("I am in platform_channel.dart file line 9");
      await _channel.invokeMethod('runJavaCode');
      print("I am in platform_channel.dart file line 11");
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error invoking runJavaCode: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

## main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:javacode1/platform_chanel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    print("You just click the button!");
    PlatformChannel().runJavaCode();
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

## myPlatformChannel.java

```
package com.example.my_flutter_app;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

public class MyPlatformChannel {
    public static void registerWith(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), "com.javacode1/myChannel");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
            if (call.method.equals("runJavaCode")) {
                runYourJavaCode();
                result.success(null);
            } else {
                result.notImplemented();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void runYourJavaCode() {
        // Implement your Java code here
        // This is where you can execute your Java logic
        System.out.println("Running Java code from Flutter!");
    }
}
```

mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.my_flutter_app;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        MyPlatformChannel.registerWith(flutterEngine); // Add this line
    }
}
```

[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSzna.png)

## Error invoking runJavaCode: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method runJavaCode on channel com.javacode1/myChannel) plz solve this error.

I want to run the java code in flutter application if anyone have another option other than this one method channel than plz suggest :).